# ttk.Entry.select_range() works with Button, but not ttk.Button in python / tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Can some one please explain why entry.select_range() works with a Button, but not a ttk.Button?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

entry = ttk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

#This works
button = Button(root, text="Select your text", command=lambda:
                    entry.select_range(0, END))

#but this doesn't
##button = ttk.Button(root, text="Select your text", command=lambda:
##                    entry.select_range(0, END))

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer from [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.tcl/SplAe3PFLUM/4edvWpGqeyMJ) says,

> However, *on Windows* (only) the selection will only become visible
>   when the entry gets the focus.

and also this page about [ttk button](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html) says,

> By default, a ttk.Button will be included in focus traversal ... To
>   remove the widget from focus traversal, use takefocus=False

So you need to add takefocus option to `ttk.Button`.

```
button = ttk.Button(root, takefocus=False, text=...)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Before posting, I browsed that same page but apparently bounced to something else before reading that bit at the bottom. Good eye!